# range(start, stop, step) but start, stop, step as variables

Tags: python

I cant seem to understand this range code, range(start, stop, step) but start, stop and step are also variables here in this full block, the output reverses the list : I'm still a beginner practicing loops, just need the simplest explanation :<

```
list1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

start = len(list1) - 1
stop = -1
step = -1

for i in range(start, stop, step) :
    print(list1[i])
```

Comment: It's because you've set the `step` argument to a negative value, so it will step backwards.

Answer (score 1):

In this code, `start`, `stop`, and `step` have been assigned values.

`start` has been given the value of 1 less than the length of `list1`, or 4.  `stop` is -1, which means that the final value printed will be the first value (remember it's 0-indexed) and `step` is also -1, which means to count backwards from 4.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just go from the end of your list (start) to the 0 element (end). End is -1 because last element doesn't count. Also, step -1 means that each step you are going backward.